# Шахматы на java

Tags: java

Всем доброго времени суток.

**Может ли кто-нибудь подсказать или помочь с идеей консольных шахмат на Java.**

Сам в java новичок, до этого решал только небольшие тестовые задания на закрепление пройденного материала. С разработкой с нуля никогда не сталкивался и уже с момента написания uml диаграммы начался тупняк...

Почему мне так нужны именно шахматы а не что попроще?

Сейчас появилась возможность попасть на обучение по java в крупную it компанию. И именно такое тестовое задание у них для вступления в группу.

**Я не прошу сделать за меня, мне просто очень нужны советы как что реализовать.**

В принципе понятно, что дожна быть доска - массив, фигурки - объекты со своими правилами передвижения, меню начальная, и т.д. и т.п.

Но как это все реализовать и связать? Пока только сделал самое простое, менюшку:) С доской начался вопрос. Ок, массив... 8х8... но, хотелось бы сделать что бы координаты передвижений фигурок были не цифрами а как в шахматах е2 - е4 например. И полетели вопросы...

Итак. С горем пополам сделал диаграммку. Подскажите плиз жизнеспособна ли она или это фейл?
http://pixs.ru/showimage/chessjpg_6137952_17805879.jpg

Comment: уберите пожалуйста последнюю строчку из вопроса. Здесь работа за вознаграждение не приветствуется. Если желаете нанять репетитора, то вам стоит обратиться на фриланс-биржи

Comment: Консольную? Вау! А как будут фигуры изображаться на консоли? И ещё вопрос — игра должна вестись с компьютером или два оппонента?

Comment: 2 оппонента, без отображения доски в консольке) только ходы

Comment: Данный вопрос слишком общий, поэтому не подходит под формат ru.SO. Если говорить конкретнее, то я имею в виду фразу _"Но как все это реализовать и связать?"_. Связать можно кучей способов - масса решений, как архитектурных, так и чисто программистских. То же самое относится к слову "реализовать" - тут уже в игру вступает не только опыт и стиль, но и парадигмы программирования. Мой совет - делать самостоятельно. Неважно, как получится, неважно, пройдете Вы или нет, главное - опыт. В противном случае, даже после начала обучения Вы будете искать ответы здесь, а не делать самостоятельно.

Comment: Доску можно реализовать, как класс, который хранит чар и инт.

Comment: @soon вопрос не так уж и широк. Человек хочет, что бы его подтолкнули в нужном направлении.

Comment: не ответы, а советы) я уже указал на то, что за меня делать не нужно. Просто действительно ступор. А из знакомых никто не занимается программированием, не с кем посоветоваться.

Comment: @soon лучше оставьте вопрос, не закрывайте. Пусть стимул останется у парня!

Comment: @Arik, на данный вопрос не может быть однозначного правильного ответа - именно поэтому он широк. Вы предлагаете хранить доску через класс, хранящий `char` и `int`. Я утверждаю, что `char` принесет больше проблем, чем пользы, поскольку вывод `e2-e4` - всего лишь стилистика. `char` хорош для хранения символов - тут явный номер. Кроме того, полагаю, под "доской" вы имели в виду "фигуру".

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev, если какой-то закрытый вопрос может перебить стимул - это значит, что никакого стимула не было. Кроме того, решение о закрытии вопроса принимает сообщество, а не я один.

Comment: @soon не хочу ввязываться в спор, но вопросов, когда существует единственный однозначный правильный ответ ничтожно мало (если вообще существуют). В данном случае человек явно спрашивает совета, так как в тупике и не имеет идей.

Comment: идеи то есть и много), вот как написать это все. подводит нехватка опыта и знаний(( ибо ни образования ни опыта в программировании не было. самоучка с нуля. Решил сменить специальность.

Comment: @Arik, Отмечу, что про "единственный" правильный ответ я не говорил. Но Вы не можете не согласиться с тем, что правильного ответа на вопрос "Я в тупике, нет идей, что делать?" не существует, поскольку все это субъективно. Уже совсем скоро нам предложат перейти в чат, так что предлагаю закруглиться. Чтобы меня правильно поняли - я не испытываю неприязни к автору, равно как и к вопросу - но это не форум.

Comment: @soon понятно, что не может быть однозначного ответа - есть масса вариантов как это можно реализовать - просто надо подтолкнуть ТС к кошерному варианту ))

Answer (score 7):

Набросаю на коленках:

1) Вам нужен класс описывающий игровое поле, скажем `ChessBoard`, класс должен тупо описывать клетки поля и выдавать по запросу (возвращать по методу) элемент поля - скажем объект `Cell`. `ChessBoard` должен содержать список фигурок.

2) Далее каждый тип фигурки это тоже класс, например класс пешек `Pawn` у него есть методы хождения, со своими правилами и принадлежностью к черным или белым. Лучше наверное сделать корневой класс `ChessPiece` абстрактный класс описывающий любую фигуру, от которой наследуются все остальные фигуры.

3) Теперь игра, опять же класс `Game`, игра должна содержать `ChessBoard`, в котором содержатся списки фигур с методом `step()` отображающим игровой шаг.

```
public class Game {
   private ChessBoard chessBoard;
   public void step(ChessPiece chessPiece, Cell toCell) { 
     //какую фигуру и куда двигаем
     //берем из списка фигуру и двигаем куда через move()
   }
}

public abstract class ChessPiece {
   protected boolean white;
   protected Cell currentCell; //где мы сейчас
   public abstract boolean move(Cell toCell);
   public abstract boolean paint();  //рисуем фигурку
}

public class Pawn extends ChessPiece() {
   public boolean move(Cell toCell) {
      if() {// правила хождения
          //blah-blah
          return true; //есть движение
      }
   return false; //запрещено
   }
   public void paint() {
      //рисуем пешку в поле currentCell
   }
}

public class ChessBoard {
   private Map<String, Cell> cells; //64 клеточки, по 8 String колонок
   private ArrayList<ChessPiece> pieces;
   public getCell(String col, int row) {
       //возвращаем ячейку позиционируя по String col
   }
   public void paint() {
      //рисуем сначала клеточки
      //...
      //потом рисуем фигурки
      for(ChessPiece chessPiece:pieces)
         chessPiece.paint();
   }
}
```

Ну и т.д.

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться

Answer (score 2):

Есть много вариантов. Я прогуглил словом "ASCII CHESS"  и получил следующее

Так что, у Вас есть шанс на все !!!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Помню времена, на консоле тоже шахматы играли. Компьютер назывался **Сагдиана**

Comment: это я тоже видел)) только в задании указано, что им не нужна визуализация, просто ходы. Я полагаю, что выглядеть будет примерно так: ход player 1, координаты е2 to e4. Т.е. доска может стоять перед игроками вполне реальная)) Смотреть будут на реализацию, логики. Вот)

Comment: у вас 2 будут играть или человек с компьютером? Если 2 соперника. Тогда просто сделаете один массив и изучите `Нотация Форсайта — Эдвардса` https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%AD%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B0

Answer (score 2):

Ваш вопрос вероятно закроют как всеобъемлющий. Однако я все же вам отвечу, ибо понимаю чего вы хотите. 
Примерно так:

1. Организовываете цикл `while` в котором проверяется победил ли кто (в каком положении король).
2. Если не победил никто, считываете из консоли команду. (Надо определится в каком виде команды, самое простое `e2-e4`, если на e2 никого нет или фигура так походит не может, выводите сообщение, уходите на конец цикла, но не меняете переключатель хода (например булевскую переменную) и начинаете все сначала (снова ждете команды))
3. Если команда верна, то вносите изменеия в игру, переключаете ход и вновь в цикле ждете команду, но относите ее к другому игроку.
4. Первыми ходят белые. То есть при начале программы заходим в цикл и ждем команду (переключатель хода соответсвенно показывает, что ходят белые)

После каждого хода, как уже было сказано, проводится проверка на выигрыш или ничью. Если кто выиграл вы выйдете из цикла и выведете сообщение. 
Как организовать игру - думайте сами (можно завести 1 объект "игра", содержащий примитивы или объекты фигур).

Что касается фигур, то можно их задать как перечисление. Однако тогда надо будет дополнительно хранить цвет фигуры. Лично мне нравится такой вариант: объявить 6 объектов, по количеству фигур. В каждом объекте определит поле отвечающее за цвет и функцию проверки команды - может ли фигура так ходит. Эта функция лишь она из частей общей проверки (например ходит может, но не может убить свою фигуру или выйти за пределы доски). Объявить также объект "игра" (или "доска") у которого массив 8*8 из базового типа (абстрактного) фигура (или интерфейса) определяющего 2 метода - вернуть цвет и проверить команду. От этого класса надо унаследовать все 6 фигур и перегрузить методы. Соответсвенно игра вызывает методы фигур, дополнительно проверяет возможность хода, переставляет, удаляет фигуры и определяет выигрыш.

Comment: такой вопрос: Как лучше сделать фигурки? отдельно WhiteKing, BlackKing и т.д. или же общие King, Queen, Pawn... со своими правилами ходов и дальше определять их цвет?  если это возможно.

Comment: Нормальный вопрос - особенно после редакции

Comment: @Andrew добавил в ответ.

Comment: @Andrew Лучше сделать по правилам. Так как у Вас так и так будут 2 колонки, одна для белых другая для черных. Так что нет нужды в Black/White.  Но создайте новый вопрос, отдельно, а не в комментариях

Comment: @Barmaley по-моему, он по-прежнему является всеобъемлющим. И фраза _я не прошу сделать за меня_ не является волшебной. Суть всё равно в том, что у автора не конкретная проблема, а великое множество.

Comment: @Regent, ну и что же, если у автора много проблем? Разве из этого следует, что ему не надо помогать их все решить? Да, по ходу дела он может (и должен) задавать новые вопросы в отдельных темах, а если его тут сразу отфутболить, то ни одна из них не будет решена.

Comment: @avp из того, что у автора много проблем, не следует, что нужно все за него решать (или объяснять решение для каждой). Сейчас выходит, что несколько человек думают вместо автора. И вы ведь понимаете, что если человек мало знаком с программированием, то общие советы мало помогут? А если человек должным образом разберётся в программировании, то и таких проблем у него не будет - будут конкретные мелкие проблемы. Грубо говоря, при больших затратах на ответы пользы скорее всего будет немного. 3 плюса за вопрос, закрытие вопроса отменили - это даже не смешно.

Comment: @Regent, Вы же понимаете, что все это просто противодействие сложившейся с закрытием (и бездумным минусованием) вопросов ситуацией. Не нравится вопрос -- не отвечайте, просто пройдите мимо. Если на такой вопрос никто  не обратит внимания, то через несколько часов он уже сам исчезнет из поля зрения. Вот и все.

Comment: @avp если действовать по принципу _Не нравится вопрос -- не отвечайте, просто пройдите мимо_, то можно снимать всех модераторов с должности, убирать всю модерацию с сайта в целом и ждать, пока сайт превратится в помойку из непотребных вопросов.[Такие вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431619/) будут просто висеть. Кто-то ещё и ответ даст на него.Пара обсуждений по этому поводу: [это](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question) и [это](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow?cb=1)

Comment: @avp я бы был не против вопроса, если бы он был о том, что автор попытался сделать хранение поля в массиве (включая код попытки), но что-то не пошло не так, и вопрос был бы в том, как исправить/доработать код хранения поля.

Comment: @Regent, вот для **удаления таких вопросов** и нужны модераторы, и есть сигнал *тревога* -- отправлять модератору сообщение. По поводу *большого SO* -- вообще не уверен, что это нам подходит. Если люди будут давать ответы на вопросы, которые *ВАМ* не нравятся -- что же, это   их право и не дело мешать им отвечать. Да и в конце-концов, помойка -- понятие тоже субъективное.

Comment: @avp прошу заметить, что я действую не на основании эмоций, а на основании правил. И правила _большого SO_ придуманы не просто так, равно как и не следование им может превратить ruSO в обычный форум. Да, правила можно трактовать по-разному, но массовая сердобольность к этому вопросу, включая отмену закрытия, мне непонятна. Вопрос, как я уже писал, по моему мнению, по-прежнему подпадает под _всеобъемлющий_. Но дискуссию в комментариях к ответу надо сворачивать.

Comment: @Regent, конечно, сворачиваем (как неконструктивную). А местные правила все равно надо  менять (например, выбросить термин *всеобъемлющий*).