# Вычислить длину дуги на координатной плоскости

Tags: python, алгоритм

Даются две координаты точек (х1,y1 и x2,y2) и угол дуги между ними. Надо найти длину дуги. Формулу никак не могу найти. Есть формулы, но для них нужны либо высота дуги, либо радиус окружности. Эти данные не задаются. Как решить?

Comment: Мне бы для начала понять как её решить. А если и реализация будет,  то просто супер

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и описанием конкретных проблем.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky как сказано в комментарии: _для начала понять как её решить_. Грубо говоря, _Я не прошу сделать за меня, мне просто очень нужны советы как что реализовать._. Вторая цитата из [этого вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431549/), имевшего вчера большой успех. А ведь тут больше конкретики, и решение (теоретическое) гораздо короче. Так что я даже и не знаю по каким правилам живёт сообщество.

Comment: @Regent Конкретно этот вопрос выглядит как домашнее задание, более того, он имеет весьма отдаленное отношение к программированию. Что касается подобных вопросов в общем: если находятся знатоки, которым тема интересна, то вопрос получает ответы. В любом случае, было бы здорово видеть пример решения, пусть даже и не верного. За ошибку спасибо, поправил.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky не хотелось бы разводить дискуссию в комментариях (вместо meta), как это уже было в комментариях к одному из ответов к вышеуказанному вопросу, но всё же: в обоих вопросах указан язык программирования, на котором планируется реализация, есть задача, которая нужна для чего-то (тест на курсы или просто домашнее задание), нет никакой реализации от автора в вопросе. Если есть желающие знатоки - я не против ответов, даже тогда, когда происходит решение за автора обширного вопроса, что вдохновляет людей реже пытаться решить проблему самостоятельно и чаще перекладывать её на других

Comment: Буду рад вашему вопросу на Мете!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky в итоге же получается, что голоса за закрытие вопроса аннулируются (как было в том вопросе), минусы уравновешиваются плюсами. Если мы хотим давать возможность знатокам отвечать на почти все вопросы, хоть как-то связанные с программированием, то тогда и этот вопрос можно не закрывать. Только я считаю, что на сайте это не очень хорошо скажется. Этот вопрос хотя бы достаточно конкретен.

Answer (score 3):

Извиняюсь, не увидел угла дуги. Тогда задача имеет решение.

Для начала, стоит найти длину хорды, стягивающей искомую дугу. Эта длина элементарно находится по формуле Евклидова расстояния между точками на плоскости.

Далее, надо найти радиус окружности. Проще всего его найти из треугольника, образованного радиусом, половиной хорды и перпендикуляром, опущенным на хорду из центра окружности. Но если лень делать геометрические построения - можно нагуглить формулу длины ходры, рассмотреть ее как уравнение и найти из нее радиус.

А дальше все просто: длина дуги равна радиусу, умноженному на угол.

Comment: На всякий случай уточню: _умноженному на угол_ - угол должен быть в радианах. И [статья в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Дуга_окружности).

Comment: Угол **всегда** должен быть в радианах (кроме тех случаев, когда он показывается пользователю).

Comment: Это вы понимаете, это я понимаю, но я уточнил для автора и возможных будущих читателей.

Answer (score 1):

Реализовал след. образом. Хочу поставить условие, что если вводится угол >=90, то не принимал это значение и возвращал к полю ввода угла:

```
from math import * 
x1 = input("Vvedite x1: ") 
y1 = input("Vvedite y1: ") 
x2 = input("Vvedite x2: ") 
y2 = input("Vvedite y2: ") 
c = input("Vvedite ugol: ") 
l = pi*sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1))*c/(180*sin(c)) 
print l
```

Answer (score 1):

**Пример решения задачи с комплексными числами и Компасом.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    def dlina_dugi(a,b,ugol_d):

        otrezok (a,b)
        c=(a+b)/2

        tochka_imj (a,5)
        tochka_imj (b,5)
        tochka_imj_ev (c,"c",2)

        ugol_ab=(cmath.polar(b-a)[1])

        dlina_ac=0.5*abs(b-a)

        ugol_ac_ad=(math.pi)/2-(ugol_d)/2

        ugol_ad=-ugol_ac_ad+ugol_ab

        radius=dlina_ac/math.sin(ugol_d/2)
        d=a+radius*math.cos(ugol_ad)+radius*math.sin(ugol_ad)*1j
        tochka_imj_ev(d,"d",8)
        otrezok (a,d)
        otrezok (b,d)
        otrezok (c,d)

        obj = iDocument2D.ksCircle(d.real,d.imag, radius, 2)
        obj = iDocument2D.ksArcByPoint(d.real,d.imag, radius, a.real, a.imag, b.real,b.imag, -1, 1)

        dlina_dugi=radius*ugol_d 

        return dlina_dugi



    a=111+222*1j
    b=333+333*1j
    ugol_d=math.radians(138.2)
    dlina=dlina_dugi (a,b,ugol_d)
    print "dlina_dugi",dlina

    a=511+222*1j
    b=733+333*1j
    ugol_d=math.radians(68.2)
    dlina=dlina_dugi (a,b,ugol_d)
    print "dlina_dugi",dlina
```

В коде функция и два ее вызова.

Немного больше информации на сайте:

http://forum.ascon.ru/index.php/topic,28124.0.html

Также приведу весь код макроса Компаса:

```
    ### coding: cp1251
    ### 2D-API|step3a
    #ug1=(cmath.polar(b-a)[1])


    import math
    import cmath



    import Kompas10API5 as KAPI
    import Kompas10API7 as KAPI7
    import pythoncom
    from win32com.client import Dispatch
    import LDefin2D
    import LDefin3D
    import ksConstants as CONST2D7
    import ksConstants3D as CONST3D7
    import MiscellaneousHelpers as MH
    x = 22222

    formula='x+1'
    print eval(formula)


    try:


        Kompas
        print "yes Kompas:"


    except Exception:
        print "no Kompas:"

        import Kompas6API5, LDefin3D, LDefin2D
        Kompas, doc3d = start3d()


    iKompasObject = Dispatch('KOMPAS.Application.5')
    iKompasObject = KAPI.KompasObject(iKompasObject)
    MH.iKompasObject = iKompasObject

    iApplication = Dispatch('KOMPAS.Application.7')
    iApplication = KAPI7.IApplication(iApplication)
    MH.iApplication = iApplication



    iDocument2D = iKompasObject.Document2D()
    iDocumentParam = KAPI.ksDocumentParam(iKompasObject.GetParamStruct(LDefin2D.ko_DocumentParam))
    iDocumentParam.Init()
    iDocumentParam.type = LDefin2D.lt_DocFragment
    iDocument2D.ksCreateDocument(iDocumentParam)







    # massivi uglov prjmich
    ugol_prjmoj=[]
    ugol_prjmoj_2=[]


    # massiv prjmich

    spisok=[]
    spisok_2=[]
    spisok_3=[]
    spisok_3=0
    spisok_3=[]
    rezult=[]

    nom_spis=0
    nom_spis_3=0
    nom_spis_3=0




    shag=300
    diametr=2100
    shir_stup=1500
    kolich_prjmich_stupenej=5
    visota_stupeni=70

    tolchina_materiala=4
    zazor_m_s=visota_stupeni-tolchina_materiala
    razmah_gor=diametr+shir_stup/2

    # stupenki s 5 uglov
    ug90_1=math.pi/4-0.1
    ug90_2=math.pi*3/4


    # Kolichestvo zabegnich celoe chetnoe
    kolich_zabegnich=math.floor(0.5*math.pi*diametr/shag)

    shag=0.5*math.pi*diametr/kolich_zabegnich











    #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++____________________________________________________________________________________________

    def ugol_otrezka(a,b):

        ug1=(cmath.polar(b-a)[1])

        return ug1


    def tochka(a,nomer):
        x=a.real
        y=a.imag

        iDocument2D.ksPoint(x, y, nomer)


    def tochka_imj(a,nomer):
        x=a.real
        y=a.imag

        def bar(var):

            for k, v in globals().items():

                if id(var) == id(a):
    #                print a,v
                    if a==v:  
                         rez=k
            return rez


        rez= bar (a)

        iDocument2D.ksPoint(x, y, nomer)



        tekst (a+7+22*1j,rez)



    def otrezok_na_rast(a,b,c,d,rast):
        ### na rasstojnii b peresechenie so storonami  ### 

        ugol_ab=ugol_otrezka(a,b)
        ugol_ac=ugol_otrezka(a,c)

        t90_a=a-rast*math.sin(ugol_ab)+rast*math.cos(ugol_ab)*1j
        ugol_treug=ugol_ac-(ugol_ab+math.pi/2)
        dlina_dobavki=rast*math.tan(ugol_treug) 
        a_rast=t90_a-dlina_dobavki*math.cos(ugol_ab)-dlina_dobavki*math.sin(ugol_ab)*1j
        tochka (a_rast)


        return a_rast




    def prjmaj(koor=0+0*1j,ugol=0):
        x1=1.0*koor.real
        y1=1.0*koor.imag
        iDocument2D.ksLine(x1, y1, math.degrees(ugol))



    def otrezok(a,b,oboznachenie=False):
        """      """

        x1=1.0*a.real
        y1=1.0*a.imag

        x2=1.0*b.real
        y2=1.0*b.imag
    #If Doc.ksExistObj(L12)=1 then Doc.ksDeleteObj(L12); 

    #IApplication::ExecuteKompasCommand( ksCMEditClear, FALSE|TRUE )?


        obj1 = iDocument2D.ksLineSeg(x1,y1,x2,y2, 1)
        obj2 = iDocument2D.ksLineSeg(x1+111,y1,x2+111,y2, 2)
        iDocument2D.ksDeleteObj(obj2)

        if oboznachenie== True:

            tochka_imj (a,5)
            tochka_imj (b,5)


            ttt=100+100*1j
            iii("ttt",7)

        else:
            a=a

    def massiv_po_okrug (koor_tochka1,koor_tochka2,ugol,kolich):

        a1=koor_tochka1
        b1=koor_tochka2

        ugoltmp=math.radians(ugol)
        jjj=math.sqrt(1.0-math.sin(ugoltmp)*math.sin(ugoltmp))

        mn_nov=jjj+math.sin(ugoltmp)*1j

        a11=a1
        b11=b1
        otrezok (a1+sm,b1+sm)
        prjmaj  (koor=a1+sm,ugol=ugol_otrezka(a1+sm,b1+sm))


        for nom in iter(range(kolich)):

            a22=(a11)*(mn_nov)
            b22=(b11)*(mn_nov)

            s=abs((a11+b11)/2-(a22+b22)/2)

            a11=a22
            b11=b22

            otrezok (a22+sm,b22+sm)
            prjmaj  (koor=a22+sm,ugol=ugol_otrezka(a22+sm,b22+sm))
            spisok_3.append(a22+sm)
            spisok_3.append(b22+sm)
            spisok_3.append("\n")
        rezult =[]
        rezult.append(a22+sm)
        rezult.append(b22+sm)

        return rezult       


    def massiv_po_okrug_obj (koor_tochka1,koor_tochka2,ugol,kolich):

        a1=koor_tochka1
        b1=koor_tochka2

        ugoltmp=math.radians(ugol)
        jjj=math.sqrt(1.0-math.sin(ugoltmp)*math.sin(ugoltmp))

        mn_nov=jjj+math.sin(ugoltmp)*1j

        a11=a1
        b11=b1
        otrezok (a1+sm,b1+sm)
    #    prjmaj  (koor=a1+sm,ugol=ugol_otrezka(a1+sm,b1+sm))


        for nom in iter(range(kolich)):

            a22=(a11)*(mn_nov)
            b22=(b11)*(mn_nov)

            s=abs((a11+b11)/2-(a22+b22)/2)

            a11=a22
            b11=b22

            otrezok (a22+sm,b22+sm)
    #        prjmaj  (koor=a22+sm,ugol=ugol_otrezka(a22+sm,b22+sm))
            spisok_3.append(a22+sm)
            spisok_3.append(b22+sm)
            spisok_3.append("\n")
        rezult =[]
        rezult.append(a22+sm)
        rezult.append(b22+sm)

        return rezult       


    def na_rast_paral (kolich,a1,b1,s111):

        ug=ugol_otrezka (a1,b1) 

        for nom in iter(range(kolich)):

            ap=a1+(nom+1)*s111*math.cos(ug-math.pi/2)+(nom+1)*s111*math.sin(ug-math.pi/2)*1j

            bp=b1+(nom+1)*s111*math.cos(ug-math.pi/2)+(nom+1)*s111*math.sin(ug-math.pi/2)*1j

            otrezok(ap,bp)

            spisok_3.append(ap)
            spisok_3.append(bp)
            spisok_3.append("\n")




    def na_rast_paral_bezl (kolich,a1,b1,s222):
        global ap
        global bp
        ug=ugol_otrezka (a1,b1) 
        ap=a1+s222*math.cos(ug-math.pi/2)+s222*math.sin(ug-math.pi/2)*1j
        bp=b1+s222*math.cos(ug-math.pi/2)+s222*math.sin(ug-math.pi/2)*1j


    def tekst(k,inf):
        x=k.real
        y=k.imag
        iParagraphParam = KAPI.ksParagraphParam(iKompasObject.GetParamStruct(LDefin2D.ko_ParagraphParam))
        iParagraphParam.Init()
        iParagraphParam.x = x
        iParagraphParam.y = y
        iParagraphParam.ang = 0.0
        iParagraphParam.height = 7.13581323623
        iParagraphParam.width = 10.55124855041
        iParagraphParam.hFormat = 0
        iParagraphParam.vFormat = 0
        iParagraphParam.style = 1

        iDocument2D.ksParagraph(iParagraphParam)

        iTextLineParam = KAPI.ksTextLineParam(iKompasObject.GetParamStruct(LDefin2D.ko_TextLineParam))
        iTextLineParam.Init()
        iTextLineParam.style = 1

        iTextItemArray = KAPI.ksDynamicArray(iKompasObject.GetDynamicArray(4))

        iTextItemParam = KAPI.ksTextItemParam(iKompasObject.GetParamStruct(LDefin2D.ko_TextItemParam))
        iTextItemParam.Init()
        iTextItemParam.iSNumb = 0
        iTextItemParam.s = inf
        iTextItemParam.type = 0

        iTextItemFontParam = KAPI.ksTextItemFont(iTextItemParam.GetItemFont())
        iTextItemFontParam.Init()
        iTextItemFontParam.bitVector = 4096
        iTextItemFontParam.color = 0
        iTextItemFontParam.fontName = "GOST type A"
        iTextItemFontParam.height = 20.0
        iTextItemFontParam.ksu = 1.0

        iTextItemArray.ksAddArrayItem(-1, iTextItemParam)

        iTextLineParam.SetTextItemArr(iTextItemArray)
        iDocument2D.ksTextLine(iTextLineParam)

        obj = iDocument2D.ksEndObj()

















    def tochka_imj_ev(tp,im,nomer):
    #    print tp,im,nomer 
    #    eval(funkk)
        tochka (tp,nomer)
        tekst (tp+7+22*1j,im)




    def tochka_imj_eva(tp,funkk):
        print tp,funkk 
        eval(funkk)
    #    tochka (tp,nomer)
        tekst (tp,"rez")



    def iii(im,nomer):
        print "im,nomer",im,nomer




    def peresechrnie_otrezkov(a,b,c,d,oboznachenie=False):  
        """ a,b,c,d -koordinati     obo=False - bez imeni tochki  """
        otrezok (a,b)
        otrezok (c,d)
        ug_ba=((cmath.polar((b-a))[1])) 
        ug_dc=((cmath.polar((d-c))[1])) 


        ug_ba_tan=math.tan(ug_ba)
        ug_dc_tan=math.tan(ug_dc)

        k1=ug_ba_tan
        k2=ug_dc_tan

        # po osi y otsekaet
        b1=a.imag-k1*a.real
        b2=c.imag-k2*c.real

        bb1=a-(a)*k1    

        xtp=(b2-b1)/(k1-k2)
        ytp=k1*xtp + b1 


        tp=xtp+ytp*1j



    ##x = 22222
    ##
    ##formula='x+1'
    ##print eval(formula)
    #    tochka_imj_eva("tp",7)



    #    funk='tochka (tp,3)'

    #    eval(funk)
    #    tochka (tp,3)
    #    tp1=tp
    #####################################    tochka_imj_eva (tp,"tochka (tp,7)")
        if oboznachenie== True:


    #    tochka_imj_ev (tp,"tp",7)
            tochka (tp,7)

            tochka_imj (a,5)
            tochka_imj (b,5)
            tochka_imj (c,5)
            tochka_imj (d,5)

    #        tochka_imj (a,5)
    #        tochka_imj (b,5)
    #        tochka_imj (c,5)
    #        tochka_imj (d,5)


            ttt=100+100*1j
            iii("ttt",7)

        else:
            a=a   
    #        tochka (tp,7)


    #        tochka (a,5)
    #        tochka (b,5)
    #        tochka (c,5)
    #        tochka (d,5)





    a1=1863.5491+ 1512.5341*1.0j
    b1=3109.8835+2252.2591*1.0j








    #   Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma
    #   Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma
    #   Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma
    #   Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma
    #   Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma
    #   Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma
    #   Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma  Programma


    def dlina_dugi(a,b,ugol_d):

        otrezok (a,b)
        c=(a+b)/2

        tochka_imj (a,5)
        tochka_imj (b,5)
        tochka_imj_ev (c,"c",2)

        ugol_ab=(cmath.polar(b-a)[1])

        dlina_ac=0.5*abs(b-a)

        ugol_ac_ad=(math.pi)/2-(ugol_d)/2

        ugol_ad=-ugol_ac_ad+ugol_ab

        radius=dlina_ac/math.sin(ugol_d/2)
        d=a+radius*math.cos(ugol_ad)+radius*math.sin(ugol_ad)*1j
        tochka_imj_ev(d,"d",8)
        otrezok (a,d)
        otrezok (b,d)
        otrezok (c,d)

        obj = iDocument2D.ksCircle(d.real,d.imag, radius, 2)
        obj = iDocument2D.ksArcByPoint(d.real,d.imag, radius, a.real, a.imag, b.real,b.imag, -1, 1)

        dlina_dugi=radius*ugol_d 

        return dlina_dugi



    a=111+222*1j
    b=333+333*1j
    ugol_d=math.radians(138.2)
    dlina=dlina_dugi (a,b,ugol_d)
    print "dlina_dugi",dlina


    a=511+222*1j
    b=733+333*1j
    ugol_d=math.radians(68.2)
    dlina=dlina_dugi (a,b,ugol_d)
    print "dlina_dugi",dlina
```